# Function local variables in cfc

Tags: coldfusion, scope, coldfusion-9, cfc

Having not worked with coldfusion before I was asked to look into some strange intermittent bugs in a coldfusion application.

After reading about scopes I believe the problem is because none of the variables in my cfc functions are using the `var` keyword, and the same variable name is used in various functions. So as I understand it the variables are scoped at page level and different threads calling these functions will be overwriting the variable causing the "strange" problems.

My question is what is the proper way to do this?

```
 <cfset var listCount = 0>
 <cfquery name="qGetElementsByType" dbtype="query" maxrows="#arguments.num_to_return#">
    SELECT elementId,
           title, PIhtml, Rerhtml,
           text, url, image, Rank, isPoll, pollId, subjectId
    FROM   arguments.element_query
    WHERE  <cfloop list="#arguments.element_type_id#" index="lcv">
               <cfif listCount GT 0>
                  OR
               </cfif>
               subjectid =  #lcv#
              <cfset listCount = listCount + 1>
           </cfloop>
</cfquery>
```

Does `var` need to be added each time the listCount variable is set, or just on the initial declaration?

Comment: What version of ColdFusion are you running?

Comment: This has nothing to do with your question, but there is actually no need for loops in the code above. Using cfqueryparam instead would both simplify the code and help to protect against sql injection: ie `WHERE subjectid IN ( <cfqueryparam value="#arguments.element_type_id#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" list="true"> )`

Comment: The version you are using is important. ColdFusion 9 introduced a new LOCAL scope specifically for use in functions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*(I hope this answer isn't too long-winded. I didn't think the existing answers gave sufficient information, but hopefully haven't gone too far the other way...)*

In CF, there are assorted scopes which variables can be placed in (application,session,url,cgi,etc).

Some of these require explicit declaration to be used (e.g. session variables must always be scoped), others can be automatically accessed when reading a variable (e.g. form and url variables can be read by using an unscoped variable) - there is an order of precedence here which determines which scopes are checked for an unscoped variable.

The bottom scope in this ordering is the `variables` scope, which is a scope which applies for the entire current page/object instance.

When setting a new variable, if unscoped, it is created in the `variables` scope. Since this is a global scope, it can be accessed from both different instances of the same function, as well as difference functions, which causes the issues of which you're aware.

To prevent a variable going into the global variables scope you must place it in the function's `local` scope. *(Technically you can place it in the function's `arguments` scope, but this will likely confuse people.)*

In earlier versions of CF, there was no way to explicitly access the local scope - you needed to use the `var` keyword in order to create the variable inside the local scope - and once created it will always take precedence (both for reading and writing) over the variables scope.

With CF9, the `local` scope is now a "proper" scope and can be accessed explicitly, so instead of using `<cfset var x = 0 />` you can write `<cfset local.x = 0 />` - the main benefit of this is when you are creating a variable where the `var` keyword cannot be used, e.g. `<cfquery name="local.qGetElementsByType" ...>` and `<cfloop index="local.lcv"...>`

You still only *need* to apply the local scope when first creating each variable, to prevent it going into the variables scope - subsequent reads/updates can be unscoped if you prefer, just as they would be when doing the var scope.
*(Although there are other potential scope-related issues with unscoped variables, such as inside of a `<cfloop query="queryname">` block, and because of this some people will argue you should always scope all variables no matter what.)*

**In summary, to make the code you show safe, you need to scope:**

- `qGetElementsByType` from the cfquery tag
- `lvc` from the cfloop tag

Since these variables are not created with cfset, scoping is most easily done by prefixing the names with `local.`

Since you have already `var` scoped the listCount variable, you don't need to do it again in the same function - you can optionally use `<cfset local.listCount = local.listCount + 1>` (or indeed `<cfset local.listCount++ >` ) but again this is a matter of preference and not needed to protect against leaking into the variables scope.

(side note: Ideally, you should use the cfqueryparam tag around `#lcv#` to protect against SQL injection - even though this is a query of query this might still be an issue, and it's always better to play it safe on security.)

Of course, that's just this function - you'll also need to fix other functions - and an easy way to do that is to use the **[varscoper](http://varscoper.riaforge.org)** tool to scan your entire codebase and identify variables that need scoping.

Comment: Thanks that's helpful. Coming from an exclusively .net background this coldfusion scoping is taking a bit of getting my head around. So this isn't too long-winded :)

Comment: Var scoper seems to think my local.varname is an unvaredstruct. Is that ok? If I first do var local = {} obviously that fixes the issue, but is this just varscoper not knowing I am using a version of CF higher than 9?

Comment: Yeah, if you're on CF9 or above it's fine. If you're on CF8 you need `var local = {}`. I guess there should be an option in varscoper to consider which version the code is for. Oh, I think there may be some script-related issues with varscoper too, which may be causing this.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what Evik says in his answer, you ought to `VAR` *all* your function-local variables.  `qGetElementsByType` and `lcv` ought to be VARed as well.  If you're using CF9 onwards, you can simply scope them using the `LOCAL` scope, eg: `local.qGetElementsByType` etc.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming your question is specifically regarding this line:

```
<cfset listCount = listCount + 1>
```

No, you do not need to use var again in this line.

However, if later in the page, you try to use access a variable named listCount, it will already have the value from the code you just ran, so you would want to recreate it.

Comment: I thought the point of var was that it made it local to the function so if I tried to access a variable called "listCount" outside of that it would not exist?

Comment: You need to `var` a variable the first time it is created. It will then be bound to the context of the function (and yes, will not exist outside the function).

Comment: @Omiron, you didn't show your code inside a function. You mentioned a function, but you didn't show your function. That's why I couldn't completely answer your question.

Comment: Ok sorry, should have mentioned the code I pasted was the contents of a function